# .Net XML reader equivalent in Android?

Tags: java, android, asp.net, xml, windows-phone-7

Hi im working on a WCF service that will return messages in xml to mobile phones, I have used Xml reader in the past to go through nodes and append content to new classes on windows phones.
**Is there an equivalent in Java android that will preform the same tasks as Xml reader?** (with relevance to my above statement)

Comment: google is your friend http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at 
http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/package-summary.html

Also, may I suggest that you take a look a JSon, which in many cases is more lightweight than XML and hence prefered for mobile devices; in JSON you can use, for example, use GSON as a parser.